# iOS - Application delegate - Calling didBecomeActive with CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I've a typical problem. In my application, I'm handling the application delegate method

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

to refresh the UI. 
As my application won't be terminated and running in background, when ever the app comes to active state, this method is being called and working fine.
But in one of my view controller, i'm creating CLLocationManager object

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self; // send loc updates to myself
```

The problem is that, when this location manager object is being created, application delegate's "applicationDidBecomeActive" is also being called which is not necessary for me to handle. How should I neglect the call when location manager object is being initialized?

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that such a call occures, but if there is no way to stop it, just make a flag in your defaults, smth lke **callAfterSettingDelegate**,and in your `DidBcomeActive` check if it was called after that, ignore this call and set that flag to nil.

Comment: Handling flags for everything is not the right way. If you keep on adding the flags the code will be filled with flags and nothing more.